# Device Errors : emulator:utoconfig: - skin pixel 2... when starting android device in VS 2019

Tags: android, android-emulator, visual-studio-2019

When I start a device in android device manager of Visual Studio 2019, I have trouble with the device errors

> Device error: emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_2
>   emulator: autoconfig: -skindir C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Xamarin\AndroidDeviceManager\SystemSkins\
>   emulator: autoconfig: -kernel C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\kernel-ranchu-64
>   emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
>   emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
>   emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
>   emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
>   emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\ramdisk.img
>   emulator: Using initial system image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\system.img
>   emulator: Using initial vendor image: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\system-images\android-28\google_apis_playstore\x86\vendor.img
>   emulator: autoconfig: -initdata C:\Users\HOME.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28.avd\userdata.img
>   emulator: autoconfig: -cache C:\Users\HOME.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28.avd\cache.img
>   emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard C:\Users\HOME.android\avd\pixel_2_pie_9_0_-_api_28.avd\sdcard.img
>   emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

Please help me get out this problem

Answer (score 0):

i am going to  explain you how i resolved this issue in my HP laptop.
first of all i checked
cmd
systeminfo

[image]

i  found virtual visualization no  in command.

after  that i  checked  BIOS virtual Technologies(VTx) Disable.
change it to Enable and re start PC Emulator Working Fine without any issue.

for bios setting you can check  below link
https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04760917

Answer (score 0):

The same just happened to me. To be honest I do not have a solution, but as magically as this error occurred it went away when I restarted VS2019.